# Nodemailer keeps refusing authentication for invalid login (not using gmail)

Tags: node.js, email, authentication, nodemailer, postfix-mta

I'm wrapping my head around the strangest issue ever right now. I'm using [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com) and [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) to send email.

The following code is NOT working, giving me the following error : `Error: Invalid login: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled`

```
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'mydomain.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: 'no-reply', // user
      pass: 'a-hundred-percent-the-right-password'  // password
    }
  });
```

But what is even more strange (and close to scary) is that the same code without any credentials specified is working fine! (But of course the email is going in the spams).

Does any body has an idea of what I could have done wrong ?

Comment: Made my day with the `a-hundred-percent-the-right-password` :D upvoted!

Comment: Happy to make you laugh haha! I just realised that it comes from my postfix configuration! Still coding after 10 PM seems like a bad idea lol